# Get content of element after it's compiled in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a directive that will insert a span to fill empty elements.

Let's say I want to list some data in a table from scope. I want to use a directive instead of having to `ng-if` everything on scope and then display some alternative. Like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="certificate in vm.certificates">
    <td fill-blank>{{certificate.documentDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Instead of:

```
<tr ng-repeat="certificate in vm.certificates">
    <td>
        <div ng-if="certificate.documentDate">{{certificate.documentDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</div>
        <div ng-if="!certificate.documentDate">&mdash;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the code I got so far.. The only problem is that the expression `{{certificate.documentDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}` is not compiled yet.

```
export default() => {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            let content = element.text();
            let pattern = /^\s+$/;
            if (content.match(pattern) || content.length === 0) {
                let fill = angular.element(`<span class="u-txt-faded">&mdash;</span>`);
                element.append(fill);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Here the variable `content` is not the formatted date, it is "{{certificate.documentDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}"

How can I get the content of the element after it's compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular.element.ready. element will be compiled.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element